# SQL Server 2008 datetime will not insert via c# but works within SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime

I am using an SQL Server stored procedure to put data into a database via C#. When I run the stored procedure from within SQL Server Management Studio it works but when I try to insert the row with C# it fails and I cannot find out why. I initially had trouble getting with the `DATETIME` type in the stored procedure but now that works when I use CAST. I have also tried passing the `DateTime` values in as strings from C# but this does not work either!?

My SP is below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SaveFlightInfo]
(
        @FlightInfoID int,
        @AirportFrom varchar(5),
        @AirportTo varchar(5),
        @TimeDeparture datetime,
        @TimeArrival datetime,
        @Price float,
        @DateAdded datetime,
        @Carrier varchar(30),
        @Url varchar(300)

)

AS

DECLARE @sql as varchar(1000)


--If the primary key is zero then insert new record
IF ( @FlightInfoID = 0) BEGIN
DECLARE @sql3 as varchar(1000)
SET @sql ='
INSERT INTO '+@AirportFrom+'
(AirportFrom,
AirportTo,
TimeDeparture,
TimeArrival,
Price,
DateAdded,
Carrier,
Url)

 VALUES ('''+@AirportFrom+''',
'''+@AirportTo+''',
CAST('''+CAST(@TimeDeparture as varchar(50))+''' as DATETIME),
CAST('''+CAST(@TimeArrival as varchar(50))+''' as DATETIME),
CAST('''+CAST(@Price as varchar(10))+''' as FLOAT),
CAST('''+CAST(@DateAdded as varchar(50))+''' as DATETIME),
'''+@Carrier+''',
'''+@Url+''')

'
    END
    EXEC(@sql)
```

My C# code is below:

```
   Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("DBConnectionString");
        DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("SaveFlightInfo");

        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "FlightInfoID", DbType.Int32, flightInfoID);
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "AirportFrom", DbType.String, airportFrom);
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "AirportTo", DbType.String, airportTo);
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "TimeDeparture", DbType.DateTime, timeDeparture);
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "TimeArrival", DbType.DateTime, timeArrival);
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "Price", DbType.Int16, price);
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "DateAdded", DbType.DateTime, dateAdded);
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "Carrier", DbType.String, carrier);
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "Url", DbType.String, url);

        IDataReader dr = db.ExecuteReader(dbCommand);
```

Comment: The short answer is probably to use [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001(v=sql.100).aspx), which can handle parameters directly (unlike `EXEC`). And do you really have one table per airport in your data model?

Comment: Have you thought about changing that code where you are adding Parameters to utilize the `Parameters.AddWithValue(@param,parmvalue)` method .. let the Server resolve the `DataType` that you are passing as a parameter.`ReFactor that entire Stored Proc`

Comment: You don't need to cast datetime back and forth in your store procedure, definitely you can make it work directly use DateTime datatype. You can first verify if your timeDeparture pass to your store procedure successfully by checking it in C# code, or you can use sQL Profiler to check what is the runtime parameter value.

Comment: I am experimenting with data structures to find the quickest way to get data out of the database so I am trying the one table per origin approach as the database us huge with millions of flights which need to have stats calculated per route.  I will try all of these suggestions and let you know how I get on - thanks

Comment: AddWithValue works, all look at restructuring the sp though and taking out the CASTs - thanks

Comment: @DamienZasikowski You can use the string version of the datetime object.  SQL will convert it properly.  I will have to look, but I think MS SQL's DateTime, depending what SQL version you are using doesn't match up to the CLR's definition.

Comment: Why are you creating all the @sql code (string concatenating) inside the stored procedure?

Comment: What the heck is all of that dynamic sql for?  You are going to introduce string parsing slowness and potential issues.  You are also subverting the execution plan caching.

Comment: Originally I had a huge amount of flight data all in one table and I need to extract a lot if stats on specific routes at regular intervals during the day.  The problem is that the data cannot be extracted quick enough because the database is so big.  As the information that needs to be extracted is for specific routes, it seemed that splitting the database into tables for each route would inevitably speed up the data access.  This method has been a quick way to test the theory while leaving other apps running from the DB as normal.  How would you suggest to do it a better way?

Comment: I don't think the string parsing will be a big issue as there is no bottle-neck adding data into the database.  The problem is getting it out!

Comment: You are highly vulnerable to SQL injection attack...

Comment: And if you are finding slowness while inserting or querying because the table is big, then you don't have indexes set up properly.  You may also look at partitioning your table across multiple file groups  But splitting to two tables isn't really the right solution.  BTW - that's called "sharding" and you would usually only want to shard when the shards are actually on different *databases*.

Comment: There's not really a possibility of an SQL injection attack because the data is parsed at application level and there is no user input into the data, it's just a feed.  The fields are also only 5 chars long so not much SQL could be squeezed in there anyway.  I'll check the indexes and see if that helps - thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27675/discussion-between-damien-zasikowski-and-matt-johnson)

Comment: I looked at the indexes and I did manage to half the time for data extraction using one table.  However, the one table per origin approach worked far better and increased the speed by 30-60 times!  It's definitely not the typical approach but it seems to work the best at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) system stored procedure with parameters

```
DECLARE @sql as varchar(1000)
--If the primary key is zero then insert new record
IF (@FlightInfoID = 0)
BEGIN
  DECLARE @sql3 as varchar(1000)
  SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO ' + @AirportFrom + 
    '(AirportFrom, AirportTo, TimeDeparture, TimeArrival, Price, DateAdded, Carrier, Url)
     VALUES @AirportFrom, @AirportTo, @TimeDeparture, @TimeArrival, @Price, @DateAdded, @Carrier, @Url)'
END
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@AirportFrom varchar(5), 
                           @AirportTo varchar(5), 
                           @TimeDeparture datetime,
                           @TimeArrival datetime, 
                           @Price float, 
                           @DateAdded datetime, 
                           @Carrier varchar(30), 
                           @Url varchar(300)', @AirportFrom,
                                               @AirportTo,
                                               @TimeDeparture,
                                               @TimeArrival,
                                               @Price,
                                               @DateAdded,
                                               @Carrier,
                                               @Url
```